# Cannot "Make Project" Android Maven on Android Studio 0.2.5

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea, android-studio

I'm trying to build a Android Maven Project on Android Studio 0.2.5

It's OKAY when I build by using command line

```
mvn clean install
```

But, when a press "make project" on Android Studio toolbar. I have this error

```
Android Pre Dex: [xpp3-1.1.4c.jar] trouble processing "javax/xml/namespace/QName.class":
Android Pre Dex: [xpp3-1.1.4c.jar] Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
Android Pre Dex: [xpp3-1.1.4c.jar] when not building a core library.
Android Pre Dex: [xpp3-1.1.4c.jar] This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
Android Pre Dex: [xpp3-1.1.4c.jar] in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Android Pre Dex: [xpp3-1.1.4c.jar] Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
Android Pre Dex: [xpp3-1.1.4c.jar] core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
Android Pre Dex: [xpp3-1.1.4c.jar] going on.
Android Pre Dex: [xpp3-1.1.4c.jar] However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
Android Pre Dex: [xpp3-1.1.4c.jar] namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
Android Pre Dex: [xpp3-1.1.4c.jar] from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
Android Pre Dex: [xpp3-1.1.4c.jar] assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
Android Pre Dex: [xpp3-1.1.4c.jar] compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
Android Pre Dex: [xpp3-1.1.4c.jar] It is also often of questionable legality.
Android Pre Dex: [xpp3-1.1.4c.jar] If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
Android Pre Dex: [xpp3-1.1.4c.jar] appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
```

In pom.xml, I have set coreLibrary = true 

This is a path of pom.xml, where config android-maven-plugin https://gist.github.com/lenamuit/30bfee3069b283f79cc4

If you have a solution, would you please help me? Thank you so much.

***Update 2013/08/21:***
I have found the solutions. I used this code in pom.xml.
https://gist.github.com/lenamuit/6290610